# How do I run tests for all my Django apps only?

Tags: django

Right now, if I want to run tests from all my apps, I go:

```
python manage.py test app1 app2 app3
```

If I run:

```
python manage.py test
```

The test of all apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` are run, including the django ones. Is there a simple  command to run the tests of all the apps that I have created?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sadly there is no such command. Django has no way of telling which apps are "yours" versus which are someone else's.

What I would suggest is writing a new management command, call it mytest. Then create a new setting MY_INSTALLED_APPS. The mytest command will just run the test for every app in MY_INSTALLED_APPS. You'll want the mytest command to subclass django.core.management.base.AppCommand. django.core.management.call_command will also be helpful.

The only problem with this method is that you will have to constantly maintain the MY_INSTALLED_APPS setting to make sure it is correct.

Comment: this solution can be made DRY by combining MY_INSTALLED_APPS with INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`. Then it's only a matter of deciding if you want the app to be run with `mytest` or not when you add it to the settings.

Answer (score 2):

This works better in Django 1.6+:  when you run `python manage.py test,` only your tests will run (assuming you have the default settings for TEST_RUNNER)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an management/commands/testmyapps.py for one of your app which has:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import django.core.management.commands.test
from django.core import management
from django.conf import settings

class Command(django.core.management.commands.test.Command):
    args = ''
    help = 'Test all of MY_INSTALLED_APPS'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        super(Command, self).handle(*(settings.MY_INSTALLED_APPS + args), **options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nose django test runner, it takes care of this.

Reference:
[Django nose to run only project tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479985/django-nose-to-run-only-project-tests?rq=1)