# Django nose to run only project tests

Tags: django, code-coverage, nose, buildout

I added `nose`, `django-nose`, `nose-exclude`, `coverage` to my buildout.cfg and ran buildout. Furthermore I added the `TEST_RUNNER` and the `NOSE_ARGS` to my settings.py. In the last step I created a `exclude_dirs.txt` and included it into the `NOSE_ARGS`. That worked so far.

Finally I ran `bin/django test`to run the tests of my project. I found out that every app inside `INSTALLED_APP` is run and that even parts of the django core models are run. How can I limit this to my project only without exernal packages?

Comment: Are you concerned that your nose is running too often?

Comment: No, but during development it sucks having 80 unrelevant tests running...

Answer (score 7):

In your settings.py file you can do the following:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
'--cover-package=your_app_name',
'--with-coverage', 
]
```

Assuming you have added all the reqd. apps to settings.py file in `INSTALLED_APPS`.
This will fix the issue!

Comment: I saw this option. But to ensure stability with a growing project I prefer a kind of "negative mask" defining onyl the packages to avoid.